# c++ nested structure initialization and accessing the members

Tags: c++, structure

```
struct Point
{
    double x,y;
};
Point p;
struct Disk
{
    Point center;
    int radius;
};
Disk d;
int main()
{  
   d.center.x=1.2;
   cout<<p.x;
}
```

Could someone please explain me the output of this code?
why am I not getting the value of x as 1.2 and 0 instead?

Comment: `p` and `d` are completely unrelated objects. I don't know why you expect setting a value inside one to be reflected when reading from the other... Are you learning from a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1171191)?

Comment: Thankyou, I am a newbie could you suggest me the  resources  and other materials for learning.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/9254539).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's go through your code line by line.

First, you created a `Point` called `p`. So `p` is sitting in the memory somewhere:

```
Memory:  p:[x, y]
```

Then, you created a `Disk` called `d`, which stores it's own `Point` object inside it.

```
Memory:  p:[x, y]                     d:[center:[x, y], radius]
```

These are completely separate objects. When you modify the `Point` stored in `d` with `d.center.x=1.2`, it does not affect `p` at all.

Therefore, `p` is uninitialized, and reading the value of uninitialized variables causes [*undefined behavior*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub), meaning anything can happen, in this case usually getting a random value.